# AFCI wired strangely

Tags: electrical-panel

Folks I want to replace several breakers in my panel with AFCI's.  Looking at the directions it appears you wire the power and neutral posts to the AFCI and the breaker pigtail to the neutral/ground bus.  Well when I pulled the panel and inspected the AFCI's already installed required by code only for bedrooms only the power(black) wire was installed in the AFCI breaker.  The neutral & pigtail was installed on the neutral/ground bus.  Is this an error and can I simply wire the AFCI with the power (black) wire and attach the neutral wire to ground?

Comment: What make and model is your breaker panel?

Comment: Yes, we need to know the breaker panel data.  Any data on the existing AFCI breakers would be good too.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add data and photos.  Make sure you use the same web browser you used to post the initial question, and don't reset your cookies.  If you need to switch browsers, then on the original browser tie your account to an email address and log in with email/password.

Comment: Well, BR breakers are cross-listed type C, and those fit Eaton, Cutler Hammer, BRyant (hence the name), Challenger (hence that name) and Westinghouse., which is the lineage.  I'm not trying to bust you, just want to catch a common error *which would explain the symptom you are having*.  I think at this point we're going to need model numbers off both old and new breakers, and armed with that, hopefully ThreePhaseEel can give us the lowdown for sure.  I'm commenting here instead of on my answer, because this may obsolete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

### You have an alien breaker problem

**You must use same-brand breakers in your panel**  (or certain *very specific* competitor breakers that are UL-*classified* for your panel, but those classified breakers are almost never stocked at retail).

Combination AFCIs detect both "series" faults (in line with the load, by listening to the wire for crackle-pop noises) and "parallel" line-to-ground arc faults (either by having a limited GFCI built in, or by listening more carefully).

Earlier combination AFCIs used the "limited GFCI" strategy, and so, they need to be wired just like a GFCI. This also means they cannot support 240V loads or multi-wire branch circuits (unless they are built as 2-pole breakers).

That's solved by some of the newest AFCIs, which use the "listening more carefully" strategy.  These are a technological progression from earlier design AFCIs. So I am very alarmed that your existing breakers don't need neutral, but your new breakers *do*.

- Maybe this is a GE panel having the fancy neutral-less AFCI breakers, and here you are coming back from the store with Eaton BR breakers because they were on sale.  *No, no, no, no, no*.
- Or alternatively your builder fit an Eaton BR panel, and used the new GE breakers because they play well with multi-wire branch circuits *(but not BR panels)*, and here you are, coming back from the store with the correct BR breakers.
- Or it could be a case that you went to an Eaton dealer, and they pressed Eaton CHQ breakers into your hand for your Square D QO panel, and that combination is UL-Classififed, so A-OK.
- Or your original breakers might be the GE neutral-less AFCI, and the new breakers are the GE needs-neutral kind, e.g. because they are dual-function AFCI-GFCI, which is A-OK.

We don't know.

Regardless, you can't leave the uncertainty, because it's dangerous.  Let us know when you can edit your question to include more info about your panel, existing AFCIs, and candidate AFCIs, and we will backfill better info.

Have no moral objection to returning wrong AFCIs to the store.  They should not have sold them to you.  Lots of lots of shopkeepers "conveniently believe" that any of the 1" breakers will fit any other panel, and while they will clip in, the stab does not contact properly and they will arc and set the panel on fire.

Comment: The Panel uses Eaton BR breakers and the installed AFCI's and the ones I purchased were Eaton breakers to match what was in the panel.

Comment: @user111642 Can you post a photo of the existing AFCIs, and of the labeling on the inside of the panel's door please?